# Angularjs how to access scope data from outside

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, scope, ng-grid

I have this poller function that polls data every 10000ms which is fine, however I need to be able to access variable from outside so that I can use `splice` function.

code for service:

```
'use strict';
//service to get data for analytics page
angular
    .module ('myApp')
    .factory('Analyticshistory', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('analytics_history.json',{}, {'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: false}});
      });
```

code for controller:

```
   'use strict';
    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .controller('analyticshistoryCtrl', ['$scope', 'poller', 'Analyticshistory', function ($scope, poller, Analyticshistory) {

            var dataToSplice;
            var pollerAnalyticsHistory;
            pollerAnalyticsHistory = poller.get (Analyticshistory, {delay: 10000});
            pollerAnalyticsHistory.promise.then (null, null, function (data) {


                //this works fine but it splices 
                //data every 10000ms which is not good
                $scope.myData = data.analytics.splice(0,5);


               //I'm trying this to access this outside
               $scope.myData = data.analytics;
               dataToSplice = $scope.myData;

              });

             //outside the poller here I want to access data and splice them
             //to pass them into to ng-grid
             dataToSplice.splice(0,5);//this does not work
             $scope.myData.splice(0,5);//this doe not work either


             $scope.gridOptions = {
                data: 'myData',
                columnDefs: 'columns'
             }
 }]);
```

what am I doing wrong here?

many thanks for help

PLUNKER: http://plnkr.co/edit/ui279rL9JZvxgUJXlkLB?p=preview

Comment: All these code inside one controller?

Comment: Yes in one same controller

Comment: You should turn the pooling into a service that can be then injected into controllers where needed

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, but I don't know how to implement it or your solution will work? see the service above. many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like poller.get is an asynchronous call . So by the time you call  dataToSplice.splice(0,5); data may not be present there in dataToSplice.

Thats the reason why splice doesn't work outside promise.then()

> //outside the poller here I want to access data and splice them //to
>   pass them into to ng-grid dataToSplice.splice(0,5);//this does not
>   work $scope.myData.splice(0,5);//this doe not work either

Now you have two options -

1. continue with the way you are doing as option 1
2. or setup a separate event handler (this can be done in same Controller or another controller) and call $emit inside pollerAnalyticsHistory.promise.then

Look at my post on how to handle events (through $on and $emit)
[Angular Js newbie - link in a controller view that triggers another controller action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25301581/angular-js-newbie-link-in-a-controller-view-that-triggers-another-controller-a/25305951#25305951)

Edit : (this should work) -

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('analyticshistoryCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'poller', 'Analyticshistory', function ($rootScope, $scope, poller, Analyticshistory) {


$rootScope.$on("SpliceHandler", function(evt, next, current) {
           $scope.myData.splice(0,5);
}

pollerAnalyticsHistory.promise.then (null, null, function (data) {

           //I'm trying this to access this outside
           $scope.myData = data.analytics;
           dataToSplice = $scope.myData;

$scope.$emit("SpliceHandler");
}

}]);
```

Edit(8/16/2014) :
Check out here : http://plnkr.co/edit/xkQM7NA91JlmHcxat0Qn?p=preview

Edit(8/18/2014) :
forgot to unbind the listener. plunk updated.

Comment: can you please help me with my question, Plunker is added. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I have updated your plunk, its working now and this is exactly what I had described in my answer. http://plnkr.co/edit/ui279rL9JZvxgUJXlkLB

Comment: Your solution is not working. It works only when you load the page for the first time. Now, if you click the platform tab and then you navigate back to the Summary page, the data are being spliced again. If you repeat this action or if you click between the pages a few times, data are being lost/spliced completely and the table is empty :(

Comment: forgot to add this line - $scope.$on('$destroy', spliceHandle); plunk updated - http://plnkr.co/edit/xkQM7NA91JlmHcxat0Qn?p=preview . Please check out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $rootscope.broadcast in service and then listen for it in controller by  $scope.on

Comment: how would I implement your solution with my code above?

Comment: sure, give me sometime. I need to do something now. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Plunker added. So each time you go back to summary page the data are being spliced each time:(

Comment: can you please help me with my question, Plunker is added. I really appreciate your help.